# variable tree-array using javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to make some tree-array with checkbox.
The problem is the last line or the 2nd array for "document.`getElementsByName`("engrName")..." it did not function same with the first array "document.getElementsByName("subName")"

```js
//for Substation            
var Substation = ["Adams","Boston","Chicago","Denvi","Easy"];
            
var Engr =  ["Alpha","Bravo","Charlie","Delta","Echo"];     


function genList(value,name) {
  const newList = document.createElement('ul');

  for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    newList.innerHTML += '<input type="checkbox" name="'+name+'"><label>' + value[i] + '</label><br>'; 
  }

  return newList;
}
  document.getElementById("Substation").append(genList(Substation,"subName"));
  document.getElementById("Engr").append(genList(Engr,"engrName"));
  
////
//// 
  var checkboxesSub  = document.getElementsByName('subName'),
      checkallSub    = document.getElementById('selectAllSub'),
      checkboxesEngr = document.getElementsByName('engrName'),
      checkallEngr   = document.getElementById('selectAllEngr');
    
function checkAll(checkboxX,checkbAllBox,xName) {

for(var i=0; i<checkboxX.length; i++) {
  checkboxX[i].onclick = function() {
    var checkedCount = document.querySelectorAll('input[name='+xName+']:checked').length;

    checkbAllBox.checked = checkedCount > 0;
    checkbAllBox.indeterminate = checkedCount > 0 && checkedCount < checkboxX.length;    
  }

}

checkbAllBox.onclick = function() {
  for(var i=0; i<checkboxX.length; i++) {
    checkboxX[i].checked = this.checked;
  }

}
}
  document.getElementsByName("subName").append(checkAll(checkboxesSub,checkallSub,"subName"));
 document.getElementsByName("engrName").append(checkAll(checkboxesEngr,checkallEngr,"engrName"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Arrays xxx</h1>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectAllSub">
        <label class="caret">Substation</label>
        <div class="nested" id="Substation"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectAllEngr">
        <label class="caret">Systems Engineer</label>
        <div class="nested" id="Engr"></div>
    </li>

<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the result you want? Just run it in Stack overflow.

```js
      //for Substation
      var Substation = ['Adams', 'Boston', 'Chicago', 'Denvi', 'Easy']

      var Engr = ['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta', 'Echo']

      function genList (value, name) {
        const newList = document.createElement('ul')

        for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
          newList.innerHTML +=
            '<input type="checkbox" name="' +
            name +
            '"><label>' +
            value[i] +
            '</label><br>'
        }

        return newList
      }
      document
        .getElementById('Substation')
        .append(genList(Substation, 'subName'))
      document.getElementById('Engr').append(genList(Engr, 'engrName'))

      ////
      ////
      var checkboxesSub = document.getElementsByName('subName'),
        checkallSub = document.getElementById('selectAllSub'),
        checkboxesEngr = document.getElementsByName('engrName'),
        checkallEngr = document.getElementById('selectAllEngr')

      function checkAll (checkboxX, checkbAllBox, xName) {
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxX.length; i++) {
          checkboxX[i].onclick = function () {
            var checkedCount = document.querySelectorAll(
              'input[name=' + xName + ']:checked'
            ).length

            checkbAllBox.checked = checkedCount > 0
            checkbAllBox.indeterminate =
              checkedCount > 0 && checkedCount < checkboxX.length
          }
        }

        checkbAllBox.onclick = function () {
          for (var i = 0; i < checkboxX.length; i++) {
            checkboxX[i].checked = this.checked
          }
        }
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < checkboxesSub.length; i++) {
        checkboxesSub[i].append(checkAll(checkboxesSub, checkallSub, 'subName'))
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < checkboxesSub.length; i++) {
        checkboxesEngr[i].append(
          checkAll(checkboxesEngr, checkallEngr, 'engrName')
        )
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>JavaScript Arrays xxx</h1>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="selectAllSub" />
      <label class="caret">Substation</label>
      <div class="nested" id="Substation"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="selectAllEngr" />
      <label class="caret">Systems Engineer</label>
      <div class="nested" id="Engr"></div>
    </li>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much Sir Adam.. Two thumbs up for you. I hope you can help me in the future..thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Like I see, you are trying to iterate over a group of DOM objects. The problem in your script is not the fact that the second array doesn't work. The first `getElementsByName("subName")` doesn't work too. You can't append in directly in a group of DOM object. I suggest you to iterate with a for loop.

Like this

```js
     
     for (let i = 0; i < checkboxesSub.length; i++) {
        checkboxesSub[i].append(checkAll(checkboxesSub, checkallSub, 'subName'))
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < checkboxesSub.length; i++) {
        checkboxesEngr[i].append(
          checkAll(checkboxesEngr, checkallEngr, 'engrName')
        )
      }
```

So, in this script you are appending each DOM objects in your group object. Unlike your script where you're directly appending on the group of DOM objects.

Comment: The one I'm talking about are the "checkbAllBox.checked" and "checkbAllBox.indeterminate". On the first list, if check the "substation". all of sub-list are checked and if i uncheck one of sub-list, the substation turn to indeterminate checkbox. Can't to do this on the second list and sub-list.